# Comparing strings by their alphabetical order

Tags: java

```
String s1 = "Project";
String s2 = "Sunject";
```

I want to compare the two above string by their alphabetic order (which in this case "Project" then "Sunject" as "P" comes before "S").
Does anyone know how to do that in Java?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

`String.compareTo` might or might not be what you need.

Take a look at [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=207) link if you need localized ordering of strings.

Comment: Note that `String#compareTo`'s lexicographic comparison **will sort capital "Z" before lower-case "a."** If you're alphabetizing mixed-case strings, you need locale-sensitive ordering. In case the link to localized ordering of strings goes dead, the thing to use is [java.text.Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

Comment: You can also use `String#compareToIgnoreCase`

Comment: You also have to deal with accentued letter  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12927962/2087666

Answer (score 129):

Take a look at the [`String.compareTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
s1.compareTo(s2)
```

From the javadocs:

> The result is a negative integer if
>   this String object lexicographically
>   precedes the argument string. The
>   result is a positive integer if this
>   String object lexicographically
>   follows the argument string. The
>   result is zero if the strings are
>   equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly
>   when the equals(Object) method would
>   return true.

Answer (score 55):

```
String a = "..."; 
String b = "...";  

int compare = a.compareTo(b);  

if (compare < 0) {  
    //a is smaller
}
else if (compare > 0) {
    //a is larger 
}
else {  
    //a is equal to b
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can call either string's compareTo method (java.lang.String.compareTo). This feature is well documented [on the java documentation site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

Here is a short program that demonstrates it:

```
class StringCompareExample {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = "Project"; String s2 = "Sunject";
        verboseCompare(s1, s2);
        verboseCompare(s2, s1);
        verboseCompare(s1, s1);
    }

    public static void verboseCompare(String s1, String s2){
        System.out.println("Comparing \"" + s1 + "\" to \"" + s2 + "\"...");

        int comparisonResult = s1.compareTo(s2);
        System.out.println("The result of the comparison was " + comparisonResult);

        System.out.print("This means that \"" + s1 + "\" ");
        if(comparisonResult < 0){
            System.out.println("lexicographically precedes \"" + s2 + "\".");
        }else if(comparisonResult > 0){
            System.out.println("lexicographically follows \"" + s2 + "\".");
        }else{
            System.out.println("equals \"" + s2 + "\".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is a live demonstration that shows it works: http://ideone.com/Drikp3

Answer (score 7):

For alphabetical order following nationalization, use [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

```
//Get the Collator for US English and set its strength to PRIMARY
Collator usCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
usCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
if( usCollator.compare("abc", "ABC") == 0 ) {
    System.out.println("Strings are equivalent");
}
```

For a list of supported locales, see [JDK 8 and JRE 8 Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html).

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can use `String.compareTo`, but that will sort all upper-case letters before all lower-case letters, so "Z" will come before "a".

If you just want to sort them in alphabetical order regardless of case (so that "a" comes before "Z"), you can use [`String.compareToIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

```
s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
```

This returns a negative integer if `s1` comes before `s2`, a positive integer if `s2` comes before `s1`, and zero if they're equal. Since this method ignores case completely, two strings that differ only by case are considered equal, for example `"ABC".compareToIgnoreCase("abc")` will return zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CandidateCode {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           int n =Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
           String arr[] = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = sc.nextLine();
                }


         for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <arr.length; ++j) {
                if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) > 0) {
                    String temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1 = "Project";
String s2 = "Sunject";

//print smaller one using compareTo() function
if(s1.compareTo(s2)<0) System.out.println(s1);
//if s1 is smaller then function returns negative which is less than 0 so s1 
//is smaller
else System.out.println(s2); // else s2 is smaller

//print larger one using compareTo() function
if(s1.compareTo(s2)>0) System.out.println(s1);
//is s1 is larger function will give positive so print s1 else s2 
else System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, you can use `String.compareTo(String)`.

But if you are sorting a list of Strings and you need a `Comparator`, you don't have to implement it, you can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` or `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

Answer (score 0):

## Person.java

```
import java.util.Objects;
public class Person implements Comparable {
String firstName;
String lastName;
Integer age;
Integer DOBYear;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, Integer DOBYear) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.DOBYear = DOBYear;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getDOBYear() {
    return DOBYear;
}

public void setDOBYear(Integer DOBYear) {
    this.DOBYear = DOBYear;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName) && Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName) && Objects.equals(age, person.age) && Objects.equals(DOBYear, person.DOBYear);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName, age, DOBYear);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Person p = (Person) o;
    return p.getAge() > this.getAge() ? -1: p.getAge() == this.getAge() ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", DOBYear=" + DOBYear +
            '}';
}
```

}

## PersonNameComparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PersonNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {


@Override
public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
    return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
}
```

}

## PersonTest.java#

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class PersonTest {
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Person p1 = new Person("Umesh","Bhutada",31,1991);
    Person p2 = new Person("Deepali","Baheti",29,1992);
    Person p3 = new Person("Romeet","Zanwar",5,2017);

    ArrayList<Person> arr1 = new ArrayList<Person>( Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3));
    Collections.sort(arr1);

    arr1.forEach(person -> {System.out.println( person);});

    System.out.println("End of World");

    System.out.println("test 2");

    Collections.sort(arr1,new PersonNameComparator());
    arr1.forEach(person -> {System.out.println( person);});

}
```

}