# Arranging strings alphabetically in binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am constructing a binary tree consisting of words from a sample paragraph, sorted alphabetically. So far, I have implemented all of the basic "behind the scenes" work to define the binary tree (constructors, methods), and I am now working on adding elements (words) to the tree.
Every word has had its non-alphanumeric characters removed and every letter in the word is converted to lowercase. I am wondering how I could enter words into the tree alphabetically? All I have done with binary trees have to do with numbers, so I am not sure what to do in this case. (I was thinking of something to do with ASCII values?)

Comment: "Any assistance is appreciated!" - assistance with what? I don't see any code...

Comment: I'm asking about a general algorithm on how to do this. I haven't coded anything yet, I'm still in the problem solving stages.

Comment: @lollercopter You say you've done this with numbers.. nothing changes with Strings. Your comparison is now alphabetical is all.. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203411/comparing-strings-by-their-alphabetical-order for coming up with a comparison function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you've done this with numbers before.

Nothing has really changed with your new tree.

You can think of an alphabetical comparison as just a way of giving something a precedence ranking over something else.

So, think of these strings as being a number, the smaller the number, the lower level in the tree the string will occupy. You're simply making your tree sort by smallest numbers first. `A` is smaller than `B`, `B` is smaller than `C` and so on.

Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203411/comparing-strings-by-their-alphabetical-order) for coming up with a comparison function to give you the "numbers" you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't enter stuff into a binary tree "alphabetically", you simply enter stuff into the tree.  The tree does the sorting.  (Keep in mind that a character string is just a sequence of numbers.)