# How to implement Insertion Sort?

Tags: java, list, sorting

Ok, my goal is to be able to sort a text file of single entry per line. Im stuck to the point where i have to create the Insertion class. How do i pass the single link list (my own implementation, not Java's) and what else do i need to pass as a parameter? Here's my code so far.
P.S The reason im using my own implementation of the linked list is because i want to know how the thing works and how the various actions done using a linked list work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Main:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sort
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in) ;
        File outputFile ;
        EntriesList list = new EntriesList () ;
        String line ;
        String entry ;
        String command ;
        String textContent ;


         // Create the new text file. If exists, it will continue to the next commands
        do
        {
            outputFile = new File("Entries.txt") ;

                if(!outputFile.exists())
                {
                    outputFile.createNewFile ();                    
                    System.out.println("The file was created as Entries.txt");
                    System.out.println("");
                }

        }while (!outputFile.exists()) ;

        // Define which file to stream in from          
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Entries.txt") ;
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (fileIn) ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (input)) ;

        try
        {               
            // Read each line of the file               
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                     entry = line;
                     list.insert(entry) ;
            }       
            input.close() ;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error. Could not read the file") ;
        }

        //Welcome message + entry counter
        System.out.println("Welcome. \nYou about to sort " + list.count("Entries.txt") + " entries. \nPlease use the following commands [Add -add new entry, View -view entries before sorting, -i -Insertion Sort, -s -Selection Sort, -m -Merge Sort, Exit]: " );
        System. out.println ("") ;          
        command = kb.next() ;

        // User Input
        do
        {
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Add"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter String value:") ;
                entry = kb.next() ;
                textContent = entry ;
                System.out.println("Entry added successfully") ;

                try
                {
                    //the "true" argument sets the FileWriter to append mode so that is does not overwrite the first time
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Entries.txt", true));
                    out.write(textContent) ;
                    out.newLine() ;
                    out.close() ;
                }catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Could not write to file") ;
                    System.exit(0) ;
                }

                System.out.println ("Enter command:") ;
                command = kb.next() ;

                list.insert(entry) ;
            }

            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("View"))
            {
                if (!list.isEmpty())
                {
                    list.printList();
                    System.out.println ("Enter command:") ;
                    command = kb.next() ;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("File is empty. Please enter records first.");
                    System.out.println ("Enter ADD command:") ;
                    command = kb.next();
                }
            }
            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
            {
                System.exit(0) ;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Unknown command. Please use ADD, VIEW or EXIT") ;
                command = kb.next() ;
            }
        }while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) ;
    }
}
```

The List implementation:

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class EntriesList 
{
    private Entries head;
    private int listCount ;

    //LinkList constructor
    public EntriesList()
    {
            head = new Entries (null) ;
            listCount = 0 ;            
    }

    //Returns true if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
            return head == null;
    }

    //Inserts a new Entry at the end of the list
    public void insert(String entryIn) 
    {
            Entries temp = new Entries (entryIn) ;
            Entries current = head ;

            // Go to the end of the list
            while (current.getNext() != null)
            {
                current = current.getNext() ;
            }

            // Last Entries's next reference is set to the noew node 
            current.setNext(temp) ;
            listCount++ ;
    }

    //Return the size of the list
    public int size()
    {
        return listCount ;
    }

        //Prints list data
    public void printList()
    {
            Entries currentEntry = head;
            while(currentEntry != null)
            {
                currentEntry.printLink();
                currentEntry = currentEntry.nextEntry;
            }
            System.out.println("");
    }

 // Count the lines in the text file
    public int count(String filename) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try 
        {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024] ;
            int count = 0 ;
            int readChars = 0 ;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) 
            {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < readChars ; ++i)
                {
                    if (c[i] == '\n')
                        ++count ;
                }
            }
            return count ;
        } finally
        {
            is.close() ;
        }
    }
}
```

The Entries (links) creator:

```
public class Entries
{
    public String entry ;
    public Entries nextEntry;

    // Empty Link Constructor
    public Entries ()
    {

    }

    //Link constructor
    public Entries(String entryIn) 
    {
        entry = entryIn ;
        nextEntry = null ;
    }

    public String getEntry () 
    {
        return entry ;
    }

    public void setEntry (String entryIn)
    {
        entry = entryIn ;
    }

    public Entries getNext () 
    {
        return nextEntry ;
    }

    public void setNext (Entries nextEntryIn)
    {
        nextEntry = nextEntryIn ;
    }

    //Print Link data
    public void printLink()
    {
            System.out.println("") ;
            System.out.print(getEntry() +"\n");
            System.out.println("") ;
    }
}
```

And the almighty Insertion sort class:

```
public class Insertion 
{
    public String Sort (EntriesList list)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should change the title to "How to implement insertion sort in Java?" :) Try following link http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/arrayexamples/InsertionSort.shtml

Comment: How exactly should i modify this so it sorts string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post appears to be asking two separate questions. So I've answered them separately.

**EDIT:** Just noticed a problem with your linkedlist class. You'll have to first fix this and then take a look at my answers to your questions.

Your implementation is incorrect because you're not storing a reference to the next link in the linkedlist. `Entries` should store a reference to the next element. I recommend reading [this article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

If you look at the diagram on that page...

[image: Singly linked list]

each link (or entry as you're calling it) has a link pointing to its neighbour.

**Implementing Insertion sort**

I assume you want to sort you linked list alphabetically by the entry inside of it. If this is the case you simply swap out the integer compare in insertion sorts you'll see in text books / on the web for an alphabetical comparison.

Take a look at [Comparing strings by their alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203411/comparing-strings-by-their-alphabetical-order) it's a similar question which tells you how to do alphabetical comparisons.

I also wrote a insertion sort class in Scala for integers last night [here](http://www.achurch.me/2012/04/16/insertion-sort-scala-implementation/) you might find it useful.

**Iterating over a LinkedList**

For passing your linked list you simply pass the `head` link. you can then iterate through the linkedlist by calling the `next` element of the list.

for example..

```
while(link < null){
  link.next
}
```

Assuming `link`is equal to the head of the list the above loop will continue to get the next element in the linked list on till null (which should represent the end of the list)

Comment: just finished the first part (reference). does that seem ok?

Comment: @voth1234 Yes, that seems right. The best way of testing this would be to create an `insert()` function which allows you to insert a link, insert 6 or 7 of them and then traverse them using the while loop I've provided in my code. That'll allow you to see that a linkedlist has been created.

Comment: i have  public void insert(String entryIn)  and seems to be working ok thnx!

Comment: So, the passing of the head should look something like this?: ins.Sort(head)    - while the Sort method is created like this?: public String Sort(String headIn)    is that correct?

Comment: You wont be taking a String into the sorting function. The head itself should go into it.

Comment: ins.Sort(list.head)      public void Sort (Entries listIn)  like this? ..i think im a bit lost

Comment: I think you're tackling too many unknowns at once. If I was you, I would first build my linkedlist and make sure it is traversing properly. I would then take a look at insertion sort and get it working for something a little less complex.. say an array of integers. I would then change the array of integers to a single `Entries`object. This object would be the head of your linkedlist. You would then do the comparisons on the linkedlist instead of the array of integers. Try tackling things one at a time. You're probably dealing with it all at once and that is confusing you.

Comment: i have my linked list (as you can see above). im sure it traverses properly. the thing that im having trouble on is How to pass the head based on the code i have above.

Comment: You pass in the head object. So, it'll be something like `insertionSort(Entities head)`

Comment: and in the main it would be something like this? ins.Sort(list.head)