# How to compare non english characters with accents

Tags: java, special-characters, string-comparison

I want to compare 2 strings which have some non English character in them

```
String1 = debarquer
String2 = débárquér
```

On comparing above 2 strings, they should say equal.

Comment: Don't worry if your `String` contains non-ascii values in it. You should compare them using `s1.equals(s2)`, assuming both are `String`s and don't have `null` value.

Comment: `if(String1.equals(String2)){/* do something */}`

Answer (score 24):

Use the Collator class. It allows you to set a strength and locale and it will compare characters appropriately.

It should be something similar to this (NOTE: I have not tested the program)

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CollatorExp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
        collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);

        if (collator.compare("débárquér", "debarquer") == 0) {
            System.out.println("Both Strings are equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Both Strings are not equal");
        }
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE:** A point to note is that "débárquér" and "debarquer" should never be considered as equal. But if you will be sorting them out, then you do not want them to be compared based on their ASCII value. Take for example "Joao" and "João": If you sort them out based on ASCII, you might get Joao, John, João. This is obviously not good. Using the collator class handles this correctly.

Comment: I tend to compare `String`s like that in Spanish using the `equals` method and there's no problem. What would be the great difference?

Answer (score 11):

To do this you can use Java's [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class. Just normalize the Strings, then strip out the diacritical marks, like so:

```
String stripAccents(String string) {
    string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    string = string.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

You can then use this to compare the two strings minus the accents:

```
stripAccents(string1).equals(stripAccents(string2))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (string1 != null){
if (string1.equals(string2)){
System.out.println("Equal");
}
else{
System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a way to compare 2 strings values in java.

```
        if(String1.equals(String2))
        {
           System.out.println("Equal");
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println("Not equal");
        }
```