# Comparing two string and sorting them in alphabetical order

Tags: java, string, sorting

I want to compare two strings and sort them in alphabetical order. I am currently creating two arrays with the strings and sorting one them comparing the two arrays.

```
String a="LetterA";
String b="ALetterB";
String[] array1={a.toLowerCase(),b.toLowerCase()};
String[] array2={a.toLowerCase(),b.toLowerCase()};
Arrays.sort(array2);
if (Arrays.equals(array1, array2)){
    System.out.println(a+" is before "+b);
}
else{
    System.out.println(b+" is before "+a);
}
```

This works but it is time and memory consuming. I would appreciate if anyone can suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: what is the goal? Could you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Hint**: All basic data type classes in java implement [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

```
String a="LetterA";
String b="ALetterB";
int compare = a.compareTo(b);
if (compare < 0){
    System.out.println(a+" is before "+b);
}
else if (compare > 0) {
    System.out.println(b+" is before "+a);
}
else {
    System.out.println(b+" is same as "+a);
}
```

Comment: If you are not in plain ascii mode this strategy wont wokr right. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12927962/2087666

Comment: Caution: ASCII values of capital letters are less than that of small letters. If cases are like 1>  a="Ax" and b="aa"  or 2> a="aa" and b="AA"...The results will be a contradiction to expected alphabetical sorting. Better convert both strings in a common "CASE" and then compare.

Answer (score 2):

```
int compare = a.compareTo(b);
if (compare < 0){
    System.out.println(a + " is before " +b);
} else if (compare > 0) {
    System.out.println(b + " is before " +a);
} else {
    System.out.println("Strings are equal")
}
```

Comment: add a case of equality too :)

Comment: Done - also cached comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you just look for an easy and elegant code and you do not want to preoptimize, in java 8 you can do like this:

```
String[] sorted = Stream.of(a, b).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(sorted[0] + " is before " + sorted[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the problem.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a="Angram";
    String b="Angram";

    if(a.length()==b.length()) {
        char c[]=a.toCharArray();
        char d[]=b.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(c);
        Arrays.sort(d);
        a=new String(c);
        b=new String(d);
        if(a.equals(b)) 
            System.out.print("Yes");
        else
            System.out.print("No");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the algorithm.