# Android : sort array objects based on a string field and take account the Locale

Tags: android, sorting

This is my Friend object:

```
public class Friend {

public String firstname;
public String lastname;
...
```

I want to sort a Friend ArrayList based on the **firstname** field, and **to take account accents**:

```
ArrayList<Friend> mFriends;
...

// Sort friend by firstname
Collections.sort(mFriends, new Comparator<Friend>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Friend o1, Friend o2) {
            return o1.firstname.compareTo(o2.firstname);
        }
});
```

So, how can I add the accent condition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear, But Collator enables to compare with  accents.
see: [How to compare non english characters with accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927913/how-to-compare-non-english-characters-with-accents)