# How would I make my custom generic type linked list in Java sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, compare

I am writing my own linked list in java that is of generic type  instead of using the java collections linked list.  The add method for the linked list is made up of the following code:

```
public void add(T item, int position) {
  Node<T> addThis = new Node<T>(item);
  Node<T> prev = head;
  int i;

  if(position <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Error: Cannot add element before position 1.");
  }

  else if(position == 1) {
    addThis.setNext(head);
    head = addThis;
  } else {
    for(i = 1; i < position-1; i++) {
      prev = prev.getNext();
      if(prev == null) {
        System.out.println("Cannot add beyond end of list");
      }
    } // end for
    addThis.setNext(prev.getNext());
    prev.setNext(addThis);
  }
} // end add
```

How would I make it so that when I add a new item, the item is compared to another item and is inserted alphabetically?  I have looked into using compareTo but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Thanks

EDIT:
I have various classes: I have a class called [Dvd](http://pastebin.com/TNGBECR3) which has methods and variables for a title(string) and number of copies of that title(int). I also have a [linked list class](http://pastebin.com/qt6CmYG0), a [listinterface](http://pastebin.com/rNEJQGZu), a [node class](http://pastebin.com/g8xtT8Ju), and a [main class](http://pastebin.com/N3yeBxr9).

Answer (score 0):

You mention using generics but then mention sorting them alphabetically.  Generics are not necessarily character strings, they are used to represent any type, while a sort property like alphabetically implies alphabetic characters.  My Answer assumes you are expecting generic objects of type `T` which have an alphabetic nature to them.  In my example I exclusively use  a `String`

You can set you code up to search for the position to add itself instead of providing it.

```
public void add(T item) {
    Node<T> addThis = new Node<T>(item);
    Node<T> itr = head;

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (addThis.compareTo(itr.getNext()) <= 0) { // itr > addThis
            addThis.setNext(itr.getNext());
            itr.setNext(addThis);
            return;
        }
        itr = itr.getNext();
    }
    addThis.setNext(null);
    itr.setNext(addThis);
    return;
} // end add
```

Then in your `Node` class, you can implement the `Interface Comparable` .  I'm assuming you store a string since you asked about alphabetizing.  [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203411/comparing-strings-by-their-alphabetical-order)  Explains comparing strings alphabetically.

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node> {


    String value;  // ASSUMING YOU ARE USING A STRING AS YOUR GENERIC TYPE T

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
        int i;
        String thisString = this.getValue();
        String otherString = otherNode.getValue();
        int minSize = ( otherString.length() > thisString.length() ? thisString.length() : otherString.length() );
        for (i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
             if (thisString.charAt(i) > otherString.charAt(i)) {
                 return 1;
             } else if (thisString.charAt(i) < otherString.charAt(i)) {
                 return -1;
             }
        }
        if (otherString.length() > thisString.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (otherString.length() < thisString.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // OTHER CLASS CONSTRUCTORS, VARIABLES, AND METHODS
}
```

In order to do this with simply generics, you would need to implement you `Node` class with the type `T` implementing `Comparable` like so:

```
class NodeNode<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable {


    T value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
        return this.getValue().compareTo(otherNode.getValue());
    }

    // OTHER CLASS CONSTRUCTORS, VARIABLES, AND METHODS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your implementation extend the java.util.List interface?

Can you simply add the object to the list, then sort the list using Collections.sort()?

Comment: No it does not use the java Collections LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out by using an insertion sort:

```
public void add(Dvd item) {
  DvdNode addThis = new DvdNode(item);
  if(head == null) {
    head = addThis;
  } else if(item.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(head.getItem().getTitle()) < 0) {
      addThis.setNext(head);
      head = addThis;
    } else {
        DvdNode temp;
        DvdNode prev;
        temp = head.getNext();
        prev = head;
        while(prev.getNext() != null && item.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase
            (prev.getNext().getItem().getTitle()) > 0) {
          prev = temp;
          temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        addThis.setNext(temp);
        prev.setNext(addThis);
      }
}
```