# How would I convert my custom linked list add method into an insert sort method in java?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, compare

I have this custom linked list in java (not java collections LinkedList).  It adds the item in at the selected position in the list.

```
public void add(T item, int position) {
    Node<T> addThis = new Node<T>(item);
    Node<T> prev = head;
    int i;

    if(position <= 0) {
        //throw new ListException("Cannot add element before position 1");
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot add element before position 1.");
    }

    else if(position == 1) {
        addThis.setNext(head);
        head = addThis;
    } else {
        for(i = 1; i < position-1; i++) {
            prev = prev.getNext();
            if(prev == null) {
                //throw new ListException("Cannot add beyond end of list");
                System.out.println("Cannot add beyond end of list");
            }
        } // end for
        addThis.setNext(prev.getNext());
        prev.setNext(addThis);
    }
} // end add
```

What I want to do is instead of adding the item at a selected position, I want the item to be added in alphabetically so the whole list will be sorted alphabetically at insertion.  This is the code I have so far but I am stuck.  How would I get it to do what I want?

```
public void add(String title) {
    DvdNode addThis = new DvdNode(title);
    if (head == null) {
        head = addThis;
    } else if(title.compareToIgnoreCase(head.getTitle()) < 0) {
        // title comes before the current, so add as the first Dvd in the list
    } else {
        // the new title belongs somewhere later in the list
        // while i less than size of the list compare and insert if its greater
        // than what its being compared to
        // also update the links for the list so the whole list is still accessible
    } 
}
```

EDIT:
I finally got it to work.  My solution is based off of Byakuya's solution.

```
public void add(Dvd item) {
  DvdNode addThis = new DvdNode(item);
  if(head == null) {
    head = addThis;
  } else if(item.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(head.getItem().getTitle()) < 0) {
      addThis.setNext(head);
      head = addThis;
    } else {
        DvdNode temp;
        DvdNode prev;
        temp = head.getNext();
        prev = head;
        while(prev.getNext() != null && item.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase
            (prev.getNext().getItem().getTitle()) > 0) {
          prev = temp;
          temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        addThis.setNext(temp);
        prev.setNext(addThis);
      }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at insertion sort - that's what you need to do; a version of that on each insert.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802104/how-would-i-make-my-custom-generic-type-linked-list-in-java-sorted/19802483

Comment: The code I've written in my answer below seems to do what you expect. Notice it is not necessary even to check if the head is null, as the mechanism should work with such case as well. Does this meet your expectations?

Comment: @Byakuya I finally got it work work. I used your solution but changed it a little. I have added mine to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create something like this:

```
public void add(String title){
    DvdNode addThis = new DvdNode(title);
    DvdNode iter = head;
    DvdNode prev = null;

    while (iter && addThis.name.compareTo(iter.name) < 0){
        prev = iter;
        iter = iter.getNext();
    }
    addThis.setNext(iter);
    addThis.setPrev(prev);
    if (prev)
        prev.setNext(addThis);
    if (iter)
        iter.setPrev(addThis);
    if (head == null)
        head = addThis;
}
```

If head is null, then you will simply set addThis next and prev to null and update head. Otherwise the iterator will stop at the first element which name is lexicographically greater or equal to your String title (so if your String title is the greatest yet in the list, the iter will stop at null, and you'll insert your element as the last one in the list, which is correct) and the prev will be the last element before iter. Then proper linking takes place.

My exaple fits with a double-direction list. If you want it to work for a single-direction list, just remove setting Prev's of addThis and iter.