# Custom LinkedList with Sorting

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list (not using Java's default, rather my own defined).
The linked list should be capable enough to add data in some order.
Like user try to insert 1, 3 and 2 in given order. The "2" should insert before 3 and resultant linked list should have 1, 2 and 3.

Above all, everything should be done using generics(as i want to learn it).

Created following classes for custom linked list, just need help to provide insertion in sorted order.

```
package customlinkedlist;

public class Node<T> {

    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Then interface-

```
package customlinkedlist;

public interface CustomLinkedList<T> {

    Node<T> insert(T data);
}
```

And respective implementation-

```
package customlinkedlist;

public class CustomLinkedListimpl<T> implements CustomLinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;

    public CustomLinkedListimpl() {
        head = new Node<T>();
        head.setNext(null);
        head.setData(null);
    }

    public Node<T> insert(T data) {

        Node<T> nodeToInsert = null;

        if (head.getNext() == null) {

            nodeToInsert = new Node<T>();
            nodeToInsert.setData(data);
            nodeToInsert.setNext(null);

            head.setNext(nodeToInsert);
        } else {

            Node<T> tempNode = head;
            while(tempNode.getNext() != null) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            }

            nodeToInsert = new Node<T>();
            nodeToInsert.setData(data);
            nodeToInsert.setNext(null);

            tempNode.setNext(nodeToInsert);
        }
        return nodeToInsert;
    }

    public void printList() {

        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is null.");
            return;
        }

        Node<T> tempNode = head.getNext();
        System.out.print(tempNode.getData());

        while (tempNode.getNext() != null) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            System.out.print(" --> " + tempNode.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is client class-

```
package customlinkedlist;

public class CustomLLClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CustomLinkedListimpl<Integer> customLinkedList = new CustomLinkedListimpl<Integer>();
        customLinkedList.insert(1);
        customLinkedList.insert(3);
        customLinkedList.insert(2);

        customLinkedList.printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please forgive me for improper indentation as I am new to this community and not fully aware of the tools.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802104/how-would-i-make-my-custom-generic-type-linked-list-in-java-sorted Though it solves some how but in case sorting does not uses generics.

Comment: Thank you Alex for indentation and formatting.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will have more success getting answers if you state your question more clearly. Make it explicit exactly what you want to know. Here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Greag. Sure i will keep in mind while posting the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to generify your sorting. 
There are 2 approaches in which you can implement `insert` method.
1. Recursive
2. Non-recursive

Here is a non-recursive way to achieve it:

```
public void add(Comparable data) { //you can generify your code and then use Comparable<T>
        Node nodeToInsert = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = nodeToInsert;

        }
        else if (data.compareTo(head.data) < 0) {
            nodeToInsert.next = head;
            head = nodeToInsert;
        }
        else {
            Node before = head, after = head.next;
            while (after != null) {
                if (data.compareTo(after.data) < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                before = after;
                after = after.next;
            }
            nodeToInsert.next = before.next;
            before.next = nodeToInsert;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sol4me for the idea. It worked. I am not good with generics hence faced problem.