# How to display numbers/strings in the correct order?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have some homework which I need help with. So I had to write code in which I am given three numbers, and by using if-else statements I have to display them in the correct order. So I think I am on the right path with numbers, but have no idea how to display it by using Strings. Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class CS1702_Lab32 
{   
    static public void main(String args[])  
    {
        int a = 9, b = -10, c = -3;

    /* These are the six possible orders
     * abc
     * acb
     * bac
     * bca
     * cab
     * cba
     */

    if ( ( a <= b ) && ( b <= c ) )
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'a'<='b'<='c'");
    }
    else if ( ( a <= c ) && ( c <= b ) )
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'a'<='c'<='b'");
    }
    else if ( ( b <= a ) && ( a <= c ) )
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'b'<='a'<='c'");
    }
    else if ( ( b <= c ) && ( c <= a ))
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'b'<='c'<='a'");
    }
    else if ( ( c <= a) && ( a <= b ))
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'c'<='a'<='b'");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'c'<='b'<='a'");
    }

    }
}
```

Now how would I go about doing the same thing for three strings in alphabetical order? I don't think I am supposed to use arrays right now as the worksheet is just on conditional statements. Here are the questions from the worksheet if it is any help:

```
Write the Java code that will solve the following problems:

1. Given three numbers, displays them in the correct order (ascending)
2. Given three names (e.g. name1, name2 and name3 as string variables), display them in the correct alphabetical order
```

Comment: Have you tried using `yourStringA.compareTo(yourStringB)`? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203441/362298

Answer (score 0):

String.compareTo  is what you want.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
int[] numbers = {-40, 2, -5};
Arrays.sort(numbers);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Same goes for String:

```
String[] names = {"Me", "You", "ABC"};
Arrays.sort(names);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong lies in this condition:

```
else if ( ( c <= b) && ( a <= b ))
    {
        System.out.println("The correct order is 'c'<='a'<='b'");
    }
```

With this checking you are saying that: `c` and `a` are less than or equal(`<=`) to `b`. Where, `c` can be either greater or less than `a`.

It should be `else if ( ( c <= a) && ( a <= b ))` to speak: `c <= a`and `a <= b`: `c <= a <= b`

For your specified problem, Try `sorting` them out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] num = {11, 2, 3};

 /*Convert the array into a list*/
   ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.aslist(num));

/*Sort the list*/
   Collections.sort(list);

/*Same for String*/ 
   String[] str = {"b", "a", "c"};
   Arryslist<String> list2 = new ARrayList<String>(Arrays.aslist(str));

/*Sort the list*/
  Collections.sort(list2);
```