# How to compare first letter of two strings by alphabetical order [Java]

Tags: java

I want to return true if the first letter of a string alphabetically precedes the first letter of another string. So if `s1 = "Adam"` and `s2 = "Bob"` then `s1.someMethod(s2)` should return true since *A* comes before *B* in the alphabet. I just need a few lines to do this so maybe using `charAt(0)` first could be involved.

Cheers.

Comment: first make them both capital or lower case to compare them more easily. then you take both chars and check which one is bigger

Comment: *maybe using charAt(0) first could be involved.* That and the `<` operator is all you'll need. Did you make any effort at solving this on your own?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203411/comparing-strings-by-their-alphabetical-order

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
1. Convert the strings to lowercase

2. Compare their ASCII values of the first characters

    int diff=s1.charAt(0)-s2.charAt(0);

3. Print the result

    if(diff>0)

       return true;

    else 

       return false;
```

Comment: can be done much easier. its just 1 if you need... `s1.toUpperCase().charAt(0)<s2.toUpperCase().charAt(0)` returns true else false

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the comment. I agree

Comment: Is this a reverse code golf?

Answer (score 1):

> s1.someMethod(s2) should return true

If you are already looking for a simple method, then **`String` already `implements` `Comparable`** interface, so you can simply **use `compareTo`** as shown below:

```
s1.compareTo(s2)<0
```

This will `return` `true` if `s1` comes before `s2` i.e., in the alphabetic order.
Also, just to add, `s1.compareTo(s2)` returns `0` if both the strings are equal.