# Compare two strings by order in alphabet in java

Tags: java, string

I have two Strings:

```
String string1 = "Abcdef"
String string2 = "Axyz"
```

I usually code in python, so I'm really new to java.
How do I compare these to strings and find out which one would come first in a dictionary(I mean the book not the datastructure)?

Comment: String have a method that is literaly called `compareTo(String)` with the description `Compares two strings lexicographically.`. I'm sorry but this question shows no research effort at all.

Comment: [Comparing strings by their alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203411/comparing-strings-by-their-alphabetical-order)

Comment: It is more complicated, because lexicographical ordering doesn't necessarily equal alphabetical ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `String` implements `Comparable` you can use `compareTo` to compare chronologically:

```
string1.compareTo(string2)
```